# Second distributional derivative of $\ln x_+$

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, distribution-theory

Consider the function $g(x)=\ln x_+$ and we can form the distribution
$$(\ln x_+,\varphi)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln x \,\varphi(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

My solution is
\begin{align}
\left<g'', \varphi \right> &= \left<g, \varphi''\right>
\\&= \int^{\infty}_{0} \ln x \cdot \varphi''(x)\,\mathrm dx \\
&=
\Big| 
\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}} 
u=\ln x & u'= \frac{1}{x} \\
 v = \varphi'(x) & v'= \varphi''(x) \end{array}
\Big|\\
&=\left[ \ln x \cdot \varphi'(x) \right]^\infty_{0} - \int^\infty_{0} \ln x \cdot \varphi'(x) \,\mathrm dx\\
\end{align}

But I guess my solution is not correct since when I partially integrate second time it gives me nothing. Any help would be great!

Comment: You have not differentiated the $\ln x$ term.

Comment: What is the question? I mean the second derivative of $g$ is the distribution defined by $\langle g'', \varphi \rangle = \int_0^\infty \ln(x) \varphi''(x) d x$. What else do you want? There are many othe ways to express this distribution, but which one do you want? Clearly, if $\varphi(0)= \varphi'(0) = 0$, then $\langle g'',\varphi\rangle = -\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}\varphi(x) d x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
\ln x_\epsilon = (\ln x) \, \mathbf{1}_{(\epsilon,\infty)},
$$
i.e.
$$
\langle \ln x_\epsilon, \varphi \rangle
= \int_\epsilon^\infty (\ln x) \, \varphi(x) \, dx
.
$$

Then
$$
(\ln x_\epsilon)' 
= \frac{1}{x} \, \mathbf{1}_{(\epsilon,\infty)} + (\ln x) \, \delta_\epsilon
= \frac{1}{x} \, \mathbf{1}_{(\epsilon,\infty)} + (\ln \epsilon) \, \delta_\epsilon
$$
and
$$
(\ln x_\epsilon)'' 
= \left( \frac{1}{x} \, \mathbf{1}_{(\epsilon,\infty)} + (\ln \epsilon) \, \delta_\epsilon \right)'
= -\frac{1}{x^2}  \, \mathbf{1}_{(\epsilon,\infty)}
+ \frac{1}{x} \, \delta_\epsilon
+ (\ln\epsilon) \, \delta_\epsilon'
\\
= -\frac{1}{x^2}  \, \mathbf{1}_{(\epsilon,\infty)}
+ \frac{1}{\epsilon} \, \delta_\epsilon
+ (\ln\epsilon) \, \delta_\epsilon'
.
$$

Now $\ln x_+ = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \ln x_\epsilon$ so
$$
(\ln x_+)''
= (\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \ln x_\epsilon)''
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} (\ln x_\epsilon)''
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left( -\frac{1}{x^2}  \, \mathbf{1}_{(\epsilon,\infty)}
+ \frac{1}{\epsilon} \, \delta_\epsilon
+ (\ln\epsilon) \, \delta_\epsilon' \right)
.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the many possible ways to express the second derivative: let $ {\theta} \in  {\mathcal{C}}_{0}^{\infty } \left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ such that $ {\theta} \left(0\right) = 1$ and
$ {{\theta}'} \left(0\right) = 0$.

For every $ {\varphi} \in  {\mathcal{C}}_{0}^{\infty } \left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ it holds

\begin{equation}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}  \begin{array}{rcl}\left\langle {g''} , {\varphi}\right\rangle &=&\left\langle {g''} \  , \  {\varphi}-{\varphi} \left(0\right) {\theta}-{{\varphi}'} \left(0\right) x {\theta}\right\rangle +{\varphi} \left(0\right) \left\langle {g''} , {\theta}\right\rangle +{{\varphi}'} \left(0\right) \left\langle {g''} , x {\theta}\right\rangle \\
&=&\displaystyle -\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{{\varphi} \left(x\right)-{\varphi} \left(0\right) {\theta} \left(x\right)-{{\varphi}'} \left(0\right) x {\theta} \left(x\right)}{{x}^{2}} d x\\
&&\qquad \displaystyle
+{\varphi} \left(0\right) \int_{0}^{\infty }\ln  \left(x\right) {\theta}'' \left(x\right) d x+{{\varphi}'} \left(0\right) \int_{0}^{\infty }\ln  \left(x\right) (x {\theta}(x))'' d x
\end{array}
\end{equation}

because $ {\psi}(x)= {\varphi}(x)-{\varphi} \left(0\right) {\theta}(x)-{{\varphi}'} \left(0\right) x {\theta}(x)\in  {\mathcal{C}}_{0}^{\infty } \left(\mathbb{R}\right)$ satisfies

\begin{equation}{\psi} \left(0\right) = {{\psi}'} \left(0\right) = 0\end{equation}